# How to calculate variance or diversity index in this chart

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, variance

[image: team skills]
The bar shows an information regarding a team, in which 5 people know java, 10 know javascript etc How can I calculate diversity in this team, or perhaps the variance if in this case variance is same as diversity index?

Comment: Variance is not a thing here as you have labels of languages rather than numbers.  Does each member of the team only know one language?

Comment: No, a member may know more than one language

Comment: Then it might be useful to know how many are in the team in total